# Как задать стили css для виджета Яндекс

Tags: css, виджет

Вобщем понадобилось на сайт установить вот такую штуку от Яндекса https://yandex.ru/dev/share/doc/dg/add.html
Функционал устраивает на все 100! но нужно поменять стиль самой кнопки.

Подключал так

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-image="{{$user->settings->logotype}}" data-curtain data-limit="0" data-more-button-type="" data-services="vkontakte,telegram,twitter,viber,whatsapp,skype,tumblr,linkedin,digg,reddit"></div>
```

Получил вот такую штуку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чуть увеличить ее размер до 38x38px и сделать белой.

Открываю консоль в браузере и вижу там следующее

```
.ya-share2__container_mobile.ya-share2__container_size_m .ya-share2__icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

Меняю на необходимые 38px и все хорошо, переношу эту штуку к себе в style.css в итоге ничего не происходит. Как можно достичь желаемого то?

Comment: Не рекомендуется, но как вариант: height: 32px !important; с шириной так же.